# error C2039: 'memchr' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Tags: c++

It has been quite a while since I am getting this error in the standard <cstring> header file for no apparent reason. A google search brought up many answers but none of them worked.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok I fixed it myself. It was a stupid mistake! I have a file called "String.h" in a library project which is being picked up by the <cstring> header. Probably because I have added the path to <String.h> as an additional include directory in my test project (where I am getting this error.) Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Man, I just spent an hour figuring it out. Thanks, it was the same problem as this.

Comment: thx man, saved me a lot of time and nerves! upvote for question and answer.

Comment: Yes, it helps! I just wrote my own string implementation and put it to String.h file. It was some time until I decided to google error! Thanks! Shame to Microsoft...

Comment: Microsoft shafts us all once again.

Comment: This is an insane error, I'm so happy I came across your post, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler may be (correctly) placing the memchr function in the C++ std namespace. Try prefixing memchr call with std:: and if that fails, post the code that causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it was something else.

Answer (score -5):

Preprocessor defines are pretty handy when you want to avoid this sort of mistake.

```
//whatev.h
#ifndef WHATEV
#define WHATEV

// your code here

#endif
```

Comment: prefer using `#pragma once` since I exclusively work with MS compilers. But in any case this is not the reason why I got the error.