# _stricmp with mingw and c++0x not existent?

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, googletest

I'm currently trying to use googletest with MinGW and `-std=c++0x` but it complains that `_stricmp is not declared in this scope` which it doesn't when I do not use `-std=c++0x`.
I have no idea what `_stricmp` is, I just found out that it is defined in `cstring/string.h`, so why is it gone in C++0x?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `-std=c++0x` option causes g++ to go into 'strict ANSI' mode so it doesn't declare non-standard functions (and `_stricmp()` is non-standard - it's just a version of `strcmp()` that's case-insensitive).

Use `-std=gnu++0x` instead.

Comment: +1 But this is incredibly annoying. The whole GCC option thing has got out of control, IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to solution by Michael there is other method for overriding `strict ANSI` mode. Include the following before any includes in file with compilation problems:

```
#ifdef __STRICT_ANSI__
#undef __STRICT_ANSI__
#endif
```

This helps not only with `_stricmp` also with other common functions like `swptintf`, `vswprintf` and simmilar.

Comment: This one actually solved the problem for me, not Michael's answer. I agree with nbt, GCC options need a serious streamlining overhaul.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/), which allowed me to run Google Tests with -std=c++11 (works with your -std=c++0x as well). It eliminates problems with _stricmp, _strdup and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same issue, but for me it was, that I've had a file `String.h` in an include path, that was picked up by the proprocessor and used instead of the standard one. Found thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531916/error-c2039-memchr-is-not-a-member-of-global-namespace).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33540989)