# C++ to C++11 in gcc MinGW missing function

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I tried to use the SimpleIni "library"... it's basically a header :
https://github.com/brofield/simpleini

```
g++ test.cpp
```

This works fine

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

Output :

```
SimpleIni.h: In member function 'SI_Error CSimpleIniTempl<SI_CHAR, SI_STRLESS, SI_CONVERTER>::LoadFile(const wchar_t*)':
SimpleIni.h:1328:35: erreur: there are no arguments to '_wfopen' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '_wfopen' must be available
[-fpermissive]
SimpleIni.h:1328:35: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
SimpleIni.h: In member function 'SI_Error CSimpleIniTempl<SI_CHAR, SI_STRLESS, SI_CONVERTER>::SaveFile(const wchar_t*, bool) const':
SimpleIni.h:2343:35: erreur: there are no arguments to '_wfopen' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '_wfopen' must be available
[-fpermissive]
SimpleIni.h: In member function 'bool SI_NoCase<SI_CHAR>::operator()(const SI_CHAR*, const SI_CHAR*) const':
SimpleIni.h:3214:46: erreur: there are no arguments to '_mbsicmp' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '_mbsicmp' must be available
e [-fpermissive]
SimpleIni.h:3218:40: erreur: there are no arguments to '_wcsicmp' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '_wcsicmp' must be available
e [-fpermissive]
```

I tried to use strcasecmp instead but same thing, not available on MinGW C++11.
I don't really understand why I can't use some functionality from C.

Is there a way to bypass this problem ?

Comment: `_wfopen` is not from C. It's from Microsoft.

Comment: My guess is that the library has checks for the `_WIN32` (which checks if the OS is Windows) macro to use things available in the Microsoft compiler instead of using the macro that checks if the compiler is Microsoft's: `_MSC_VER`.

Comment: Yep, that's it: https://github.com/brofield/simpleini/blob/master/SimpleIni.h#L1323.

Comment: Microsoft... I should have known with the underscore. I replaced all the _WIN32 to _MSC_VER and the error just flew away. Well done.

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to file a bug or pull request!

Comment: This related thread fix the problem too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312151/stricmp-with-mingw-and-c0x-not-existent?rq=1